# How to install R language version 4 in AWS EMR - Amazon linux 2

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, amazon-linux

We have an AWS EMR cluster. By default it comes with

```
Amazon Linux version 2
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30) -- "Kite-Eating Tree"
```

I like to install latest R version 4.*.*

Tried following :

```
yum -y install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
yum -y install R
```

But it doesn't upgrade R version to v4.0. It only offers to upgrade it to `3.4.3-1.amzn2.0.1`

Amazon Linux 2 - uses EPEL version 7. [EPEL v7](https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/r/) doesn't seem to have R v4.
But [EPEL version 8 has R v4](https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/epel/8/Everything/x86_64/Packages/r/)

I am planning to install R from source. But like to know if this is a way to install binary.

Is there any option to install latest R binary on AWS Linux 2 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a way to install the R v4 binary from AWS extras repo

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install R4
```

In future, if some one is hunting for AWS Linux specific software package., this command list the packages that can be installed from AWS extras

```
amazon-linux-extras list
```

Reference - [Amazon Linux User Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/amazon-linux-ami-basics.html#extras-library)

Answer (score 1):

1. Install miniconda https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html
2. `conda install r-base` or `conda install r-essentials`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I couldn't make peace with installing miniconda just to install another package.

Comment: You will love using conda. Use it to install anything analysis-wise (other than general system tools). Your libraries and packages will all be harmonized. Also installing via conda is MUCH faster than `install.packages` which builds from source.

Comment: You can use Rstudio Package Manager public for specific linux like centos 7 or centos 8 and install packages from binaries instead source. https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/client/#/repos/1/overview

Comment: I don't think you can beat conda for reliability and flexibility. It's becoming more and more standard (as in packages saying to install that way) and it's cross platform. And reproducible. `conda env export -n myenv > myenv.yml`. `conda create -n myenv -f myenv.yml`.